# Rename entries in pandas dataframe based on cutoff number of entry combinations

Tags: python, pandas

To get rid of some uncommon combinations of values that are likely noise in my data set, I only want to keep combinations of entries that are reasonably common (for the sake of the test example, more common than occurring once). The remaining ones, I'd like to clump up in a sort of "Others" category.

Here is a toy data set to describe and test my problem:

```
# Make a data frame for test

details = {
    'Name' : ['Sharon', 'Aisha', 'Shaurya', 'Shahul', 'Rhonda', 'Latifa', 'Raja', 'Mia'],
    'Age' : [23, 21, 22, 21, 30, 21, 21, 23],
    'University' : ['WU', 'JNU', 'DBU', 'BHU', 'JNU', 'WU', 'JNU', 'WU'],
}
  
df = pd.DataFrame(details)
```

Here is how common the entry combinations of "age" and "university" are.

```
df.groupby(['Age', 'University']).size()

Age  University
21   BHU           1
     JNU           2
     WU            1
22   DBU           1
23   WU            2
30   JNU           1
dtype: int64
```

In the cases where the number of entries of a certain combination between university and age is less than 2, I'd like to replace the "University" value with "Other". How do I go about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A useful trick with groupbys is to get your result back to the same shape (i.e. index) than the original object by using `.transform('count')`, instead of something that aggregates values such as `.size()` or `.agg('count')`:

```
>>> count = df.groupby(['Age', 'University'])['Name'].transform('count')
>>> count
   Name
0     2
1     2
2     1
3     1
4     1
5     1
6     2
7     2
```

We can now simply use `.where()` using this series to only keep values that are 2 or higher:

```
>>> df['University'].where(count >= 2, 'Other')
0       WU
1      JNU
2    Other
3    Other
4    Other
5    Other
6      JNU
7       WU
Name: University, dtype: object
```

Note that there is a slight subtlety, with `size` you get the number of rows (in the groups, globally) and with `count` you get the number of non-`NaN` values, which applies to a specific column. Hence the `['Name']` before `.transform`.

```
>>> df['University'] = df['University'].where(count >= 2, 'Other')
>>> df
      Name  Age University
0   Sharon   23         WU
1    Aisha   21        JNU
2  Shaurya   22      Other
3   Shahul   21      Other
4   Rhonda   30      Other
5   Latifa   21      Other
6     Raja   21        JNU
7      Mia   23         WU
```